# Bulk add tasks to multiple user stories in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops

I have a bunch of user stories that are very similar, and the tasks that are associated with the user stories are all the same. Is it possible to bulk add the same tasks to multiple user stories at one time without having to go into each user story and create tasks individually?

We are using the web portal for Visual Studio Team Services (formerly Visual Studio Online).

Comment: What are the tasks supposed to represent? They might be better served as columns on the backlog.

Comment: We are converting an application from legacy code over to .NET. The app runs a bunch of reports, so a typical user story would be "<Report Name">, with tasks like "Convert legacy code", "Check against existing report for data consistency", "Unit Test", etc. Those tasks are then the same for each report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Excel to do this. Refer to this link for details: [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel). Mainly steps: [Add linked backlog items and tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel#Addlinkedbacklogitemsandtasks)